# Put Debug Info and Error Info into two different log file (Log4net)

Tags: log4net

I am using NHibernate and log4net. This is a snapshot of my error log file, using a release version of my software:

```
INFO 2009-04-28 03:07:06 - processing cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for: bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.Job
INFO 2009-04-28 03:07:06 - cascade NHibernate.Engine.CascadingAction+SaveUpdateCascadingAction for collection: bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.Job.JobItems
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - cascading to saveOrUpdate: bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.JobItem
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - unsaved-value: 0
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - transient instance of: bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.JobItem
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - saving transient instance
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - saving [bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.JobItem#<null>]
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - executing insertions
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - executing identity-insert immediately
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - Inserting entity: bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.JobItem (native id)
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - Opened new IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 1
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - Building an IDbCommand object for the SqlString: INSERT INTO job_items (FileName, Job_Id, Status) VALUES (?, ?, ?)
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - Dehydrating entity: [bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.JobItem#<null>]
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - binding 'Blue hills.jpg' to parameter: 0
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - binding '8' to parameter: 1
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - binding '1' to parameter: 2
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - INSERT INTO job_items (FileName, Job_Id, Status) VALUES (?p0, ?p1, ?p2); ?p0 = 'Blue hills.jpg', ?p1 = '8', ?p2 = '1'
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - Obtaining IDbConnection from Driver
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - Closed IDbCommand, open IDbCommands: 0
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - aggressively releasing database connection
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - Closing connection
DEBUG2009-04-28 03:07:06 - could not insert: [bpojob.Generated.BusinessObjects.JobItem]
[ INSERT INTO job_items (FileName, Job_Id, Status) VALUES (?p0, ?p1, ?p2) ]

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Duplicate entry 'Blue hills.jpg' for key 'Unique'
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadPacket()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.ReadResult(UInt64& affectedRows, Int64& lastInsertId)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.GetResultSet()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
   at NHibernate.AdoNet.AbstractBatcher.ExecuteNonQuery(IDbCommand cmd)
   at NHibernate.Id.Insert.AbstractSelectingDelegate.PerformInsert(SqlCommandInfo insertSQL, ISessionImplementor session, IBinder binder)
```

As you can see, all the `info`, `debug` and `exception` are cobbled together, making it extremely hard to sift through the file and look for information once bugs come out.

I want to put all the exception info into a file, and put other info into another file. And I want to exclude the debug information is **release mode**. How to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your log4net.xml use a different file appender logger for Error and Warning

See [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/manual/configuration.html) for more info

Comment: Lots of info in that link, would upvote if you posted the relevant section here

Comment: We write to SO for fast code/config snippets, not for link to the official documentation. Minus 1.

Comment: Agreed - it was written long before that was policy. I'll update it.

Answer (score 5):

In the below code i am using two log files using two appender(one for Debug,another for Fatal)

```
<log4net>
<appender name="FatalErrorLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="C:\temp\Host.log" />
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
  <rollingStyle value="Size" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
     <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
     <levelMin value="ERROR" />
     <levelMax value="FATAL" />
  </filter>
</appender>

<appender name="DebugLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
<file value="C:\temp\HostDebug.log" />
<appendToFile value="true" />
<maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
<maxSizeRollBackups value="50" />
<rollingStyle value="Size" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
  <conversionPattern value="%identity------%username------%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
</layout>
<filter type="log4net.Filter.LevelRangeFilter">
  <levelMin value="DEBUG" />
  <levelMax value="ERROR" />
</filter>
</appender>
</log4net>
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use a Log Parser to filter/order the data in any way you choose?

[Log4Net Dashboard](http://www.l4ndash.com/) is a good tool for this purpose (and it has a [free developer version](http://www.l4ndash.com/Download.aspx)).

Comment: It seems the links are dead by now. There's another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4774898/dashboard-for-log4net) looking for alternatives (albeit l4ndash is listed there as well).