# Dashboard for Log4Net

Tags: asp.net, log4net, asp.net-3.5, dashboard

I am using Log4Net in my asp.net application to log the errors in the database. I am looking for a dashboard which is open source/free and can display the summary on the screen and related documentation. Anyone has used dashboard for Log4Net or any recommendation?

Comment: Bear in mind that if you use an open source product in a commercial application you WILL fall in copyright issues. See how *permissive* the license is, and if you are merely redistributing an open source product or creating a derivative product, which often requires you to share code with community!!

Comment: djechelon: +1 Thanks for sharing this information. But the application is something like for their internal use and it's not a product. Is it fine now to use open source? Please guide.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, the only comprehensive *dashboard* is [Log4net Dashboard](http://www.l4ndash.com/), but it's a commercial product.

Another interesting product, that is not open source but is free and has lots of useful functions is [Log4view](http://www.log4view.com/), but less functions than Log4net Dashboard

Comment: I believe Log4View is not free, it's free for trial (30 days)

Comment: After trial, you can continue using it forever

Comment: Does Log4Net Dashboard still operate? The website seems to be down for weeks now!

Answer (score 0):

I've used this in the past http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/logviewer.aspx

Comment: Is it going to work with taking data from Sql Server?

Comment: @Zerotoinfinite I don't think so, I think it just scans the xml log files.